# How to remove small insects from broccoli?

Tags: vegetables, flowers, insects, broccoli

I'm growing up vegetables (without any chemical products) and among them broccoli. They are good, but they've a big problem: they're full of very small insects, and when I cook them, I find them in my dish. This isn't very nice.

How do you keep far away your dish these small boring insects?

How can I eat my broccoli without insects? they hid themselves within broccoli and don't go away even if I wash broccoli with flowing water, neither if I put them in water with salt... :(

Comment: I just stumbled across this old question because I was about to ask the same thing.  Did you try soaking your broccoli submerged in salt water for a 5-10 minutes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a powder called diatomaceous earth that you purchase which has microscopic edges that cut the insects' waxy coat and dehydrates them. It's also edible so don't  worry about it getting on your plants. It can also be ingested daily to reduce waste in the colon and gives you glowing skin.

Answer (score 4):

You need to grow your broccoli with a floating row cover as described [here](https://extension.umd.edu/growit/beyond-basics/floating-row-cover).  The cover allows light and water in but prevents the adults from laying eggs on your vegetables. It is re-usable, not too expensive and has the added advantage of protecting your crop from late frost in spring or early frost in the fall.

I do not know of any way to efficiently remove insects in broccoli. Kids in my house have enough issues with it already, add some insects and they won't go near it, washed or not.

Comment: what are the insects we are referring to?  I have a row cover but some small black bugs (size of aphids) are getting through the row cover.  Also, the link you included is not working

Comment: @JStorage    The new ink states that floating row cover protects against "damaging flea beetles, cutworms, Colorado potato beetle, and aphids in the spring"

Answer (score -1):

I also had this problem. they are called aphids. 
Ladybugs eat them so plant lady bug plant attractors.
Dont grow anything in the cabbage family for a year. 
You still have radish/beet/chard/etc

Comment: Sunrise said in the question that they were boring insects.